# How do I change default message for permissions for Location manager in iOS 4?

Tags: ios4, dialog, message, cllocationmanager

I get a dialog box saying:

> "my app" would like to use your current location

I want to change this message. I don't want to add anything to it. I just want to change this message. locationmanager set purpose will add a message to it, which I don't want.

Comment: Changing the default text of the dialog might allow developers to get location data while claiming that they want to 'post data to the internet' or some equally innocuous message, which is deceptive.

Comment: Can the below answer be accepted, Nik? While this is not strictly mandatory, it is helpful for other readers if you can do so.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that there is a way for changing this message. This is the default message that iOS presents on every app which uses location services and it is the same for all the applications.